# Deploy Phoenix application in Heroku, but result in application error

Tags: heroku, deployment, web-deployment, phoenix-framework

I'm deployed my application in Heroku, but although deploy ok,  in browser show view:

[image]

The Only clue of error is in log of application:

```
  : State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-31T020 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
1]: Starting process with command `MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server`
 
 =INFO REPORT==== 31-Mar-2017::02:20:04 ===
     application: boom_one
     exited: {{shutdown,
               {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.BoomOne.Endpoint',
                {shutdown,
                 {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.Server',
                  {shutdown,
                   {failed_to_start_child,
                    {ranch_listener_sup,'Elixir.BoomOne.Endpoint.HTTP'},
                    {'EXIT',
                     {noproc,
                      {gen_server,call,
                       [ranch_server,
                        {set_new_listener_opts,'Elixir.BoomOne.Endpoint.HTTP',
                         16384,
                         [{env,
                             [{'_',[],
                               [{[<<"socket">>,<<"websocket">>],
                           [{dispatch,
                                 [],'Elixir.Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket',
                                 {'Elixir.Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket',
                                  {'Elixir.BoomOne.Endpoint',
                                   'Elixir.BoomOne.UserSocket',websocket}}},
                                 {'Elixir.BoomOne.Endpoint',
                                {'_',[],'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler',
                                  []}}]}]}]}]}]}}}}}}}}},
              {'Elixir.BoomOne',start,[normal,[]]}}
     type: permanent
 ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(Mix.State, {:get, {Map, :get, [:debug, false]}}, 5000)
     ** (EXIT) no process
     (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:65: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
     (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
     (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:596: GenServer.call/3
 
 {"init terminating in do_boot",{noproc,{gen_server,call,[elixir_config,{get_and_put,at_exit,[]}]}}}
 
 init terminating in do_boot ()
 Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
1]: Process exited with status 1
1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I followed this [phoenix page tutorial on heroku](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by hardcoding "secret_key_base" setting instead of reading from system environment variable. This solution is not generally recommended as it exposes the secret key in the code repository but it might help debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks Gal T. , 

I setting hardcoding "secret_key_base" in file **prod.exs**, but the error continued.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has solution. As mentioned in [elixirforum.com](https://elixirforum.com/t/deploy-phoenix-application-in-heroku-but-result-in-application-error/4394/5), you have to change the elixir version from 1.3 to 1.4